# Java JScrollPane toggle autoscroll on/off

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea, autoscroll

I got a JtextArea in a JScrollPane and want to switch between AutoScroll on/off.

EDIT: AutoScroll - permanent scrolled down to the Bottom when JTextArea becomes extended

For Autoscroll i use:

`DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret();
 caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);`

Which works fine. 
As switch i use a Checkbox:

```
    JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("AutoScroll");
    chckbxNewCheckBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){
                caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
            } else {
                caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
            }
        }
    });
```

With this Method i am able to switch from the default "on" to "off". But switching "on" again does not work.
The JtextArea is not editable.

Thanks =)

Comment: Please clarify what “Autoscroll” means.  It appears you are not referring to the [Autoscroll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/Autoscroll.html) drag-and-drop behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Another option might be to use [Smart Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/) which allows the user to control scrolling by positioning the scrollbar.